# Upserting in GreenPlum

Tags: greenplum

How can I upsert a record in GreenPlum while copying the data from a CSV file. The CSV file has multiple records for a given value of the primary key. If a row with some value already exists in the database I want to update that record. Otherwise, it should append a new row.

Comment: Short answer is delete and then insert.  I wrote a blog post a long time ago on how to do it: http://www.pivotalguru.com/?p=104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to copy the data to a staging table, then insert/update from that table.

Here is an example of that:

```
-- Duplicate the definition of your table.
CREATE TEMP TABLE my_table_stage (LIKE my_table INCLUDING DEFAULTS);


-- Your COPY statment
COPY my_table FROM 'my_file.csv' ...


-- Insert any "new" records
INSERT INTO my_table (key_field, data_field1, data_field2)
SELECT
    stg.key_field,
    stg.data_field1,
    stg.data_field2
FROM
    my_table_stage stg
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE key_field = stg.key_field);


-- Update any existing records
UPDATE my_table orig
SET
    data_field1 = stg.data_field1,
    data_field2 = stg.data_field2
FROM
    my_table_stage stg
WHERE
    orig.key_field = stg.keyfield;
```

Comment: How about doing it from an external table instead of a staging table?

Comment: What do you mean by external table?

Comment: http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/520/admin_guide/external/g-working-with-file-based-ext-tables.html

Comment: Ok, but how is this related to your question? Is this a separate question you are asking?

Comment: No, instead of creating a staging table an external table that points to the CSV can be created and from that external table data can be inserted into the physical table the way you have suggested. This saves one step of creating the staging table.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like you know what you are doing. What is your question? The only difference is what you just explained. The rest is the same.